# App cellular settings lost when toggling Airplane mode

Tags: ios, settings, cellular-data

On iOS 8.4 on iPhone 5s, I noticed that if I set Cellular > App Store > Off, kill Setting app, then activate Airplane Mode, deactivate Airplane Mode, launch Settings, Cellular > App Store  is now On (Green).   Toggling Airplane mode flipped the setting.  This is true for a number of Apple apps.    Why does this happen and what can be done so that my preferences are retained when toggling Airplane mode?

Comment: Can't repro - same OS, same phone. Try resetting it.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to this would be to [backup and reinstall the OS.](https://support.apple.com/ht1414)